# How to get set of active slides in bxslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Was just integrating bxslider into my website and i have a requirement , where in i need the current set of active /visible images in the slider, see an example of bxslide **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/1119/)**.

The jQuery init code is below:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   mode: 'vertical',
  infiniteLoop: true,
  pager: false,
  minSlides:3,
  slideMargin:10
});
```

Now i tried all the methods in the public API, the closest that came to my requirement is `onSlideAfter` , so i tried using it like so:

```
var bxslider = $('.bx-slider').bxSlider({
          mode: 'vertical',
          minSlides: 3,
          slideWidth:304,
          onSlideAfter: function(elem , old , newi){
                var idx = elem.index(),
                src = $('.bx-slider li').eq(idx).find('img').attr('src');
                console.log(elem.index());
                $('.active-project-img img').attr('src' , src);
          }
    });
```

but `elem` , is neither the set of active elements nor is it the first active element as i actually assumed it to be.

One more solution that would have worked with a slide plugin is , getting all the visible elements , but the problem is bxsider does't hide any elements in the first place.

can anybody help me get the set of active/visible elements please ?

**EDIT**: **[Bxslider API](http://bxslider.com/options)**

Thank you.

Comment: have you check . http://bxslider.com/options

Comment: @urfusion yuppps !! see the public methods section , i tried all !

Comment: What defines an *active* slide or a set thereof as it pertains to bxSlider? Is there an equivalent of an `.active` class? What state , condition met, etc.. determines a slide active?

Comment: @zer00ne so far i can see nothing !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik ok, let me rephrase the question...what do you mean when you say *active slides*?

Comment: The slides that are inview :D and bxslider does't add a `.active` class or make the elements out of view `display:none` or invisible .. which makes it difficult to get the set of elements which are in view ! there is a method `getCurrentSlide` which returns the `index()` of the current slide(if there are 12 elements and 4 are active at a time , the no. of slides are 3 , so the index's will be 0,1,2 ... i wish this method returned the set of active eleménts instead of the indexs).

Answer (score 1):

Just as what you mentioned, as bxslider plays tricks by fixing viewpoint height and use transform, thus there is no easy way to get all active slides.

During testing, I found bxslider somehow make duplications `.bx-clone` into the list. To avoid wrong calculation, I put `.not('.bx-clone')` to exclude them.

**Bellowing should satisfy your need**.

```
var minslide = 3; // for later usage
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'vertical',
  infiniteLoop: true,
  pager: false,
  minSlides:3,
  slideMargin:10,
  onSlideAfter: function(elem, old, newi){
    // calculate offset
    si = minslide*newi;
    ei = minslide*(newi+1);
    active_slides = $('.bxslider li').not('.bx-clone').slice(si, ei);  // key point
    console.log(active_slides);       
  }
});
```

The calculation part is not complete though (probably not divide evenly), but you can fix it.